# Add Custom Argument Completer for Cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, chocolatey

How do I add dynamic argument tab completion to a PowerShell Cmdlet?

When I type this and hit `tab`, I'd like for it to do tab completion.

```
PM> Paket-Add -NuGet FSharp.Co
```

These are the values I'd like to use in this example:

```
PM> Paket-FindPackages -SearchText FSharp.Co
FSharp.Core
FSharp.Core.3
FSharp.Configuration
FSharp.Core.Fluent-3.1
FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0
FSharp.Compiler.Tools
FSharp.Compatibility.Scala
FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml
FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom
FSharp.Compiler.Service
FSharp.Control.Reactive
FSharp.Compatibility.Haskell
FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.Numerics
FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.Format
FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.System
FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq
FSharp.Compatibility.StandardML
FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.LexYacc
FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120154/23059) that gave a couple of helpful links and said I should run `Get-Content function:TabExpansion2`:

[image]

It looks like [CommandCompletion.CompleteInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.commandcompletion.completeinput(v=vs.85).aspx) needs to implemented. I thought I read somewhere that there is a `Hashtable` of commands to functions. If so, where is it and how do I install custom ones? I'm using Chocolatey to distribute [Paket.PowerShell](https://chocolatey.org/packages/paket.powershell). Here is the [Cmdlet code](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/master/src/Paket.PowerShell/PowerShell.fs).

UPDATE 2015-06-20:

I ended up getting it to work with the code here:
https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/76de1c44853ce09029ba157855525f435d951b85/src/Paket.PowerShell/ArgumentTabCompletion.ps1

```
# https://github.com/mariuszwojcik/RabbitMQTools/blob/master/TabExpansions.ps1
function createCompletionResult([string]$text, [string]$value, [string]$tooltip) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value)) { return }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($text)) { $text = $value }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($tooltip)) { $tooltip = $value }
    $completionText = @{$true="'$value'"; $false=$value  }[$value -match "\W"]
    $completionText = $completionText -replace '\[', '``[' -replace '\]', '``]'
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult $completionText, $text, 'ParameterValue', $tooltip | write
}

$findPackages = {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameter)
    Paket-FindPackages -SearchText $wordToComplete -Max 100 | % {
        createCompletionResult $_ $_ $_ | write
    }
}

$findPackageVersions = {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameter)
    if (-not $fakeBoundParameter.NuGet){ return }
    Paket-FindPackageVersions -Name $fakeBoundParameter.NuGet -Max 100 | % {
        createCompletionResult $_ $_ $_ | write
    }
}

# create and add $global:options to the list of completers
# http://www.powertheshell.com/dynamicargumentcompletion/
if (-not $global:options) { $global:options = @{CustomArgumentCompleters = @{};NativeArgumentCompleters = @{}}}

$global:options['CustomArgumentCompleters']['Paket-Add:NuGet'] = $findPackages
$global:options['CustomArgumentCompleters']['Paket-Add:Version'] = $findPackageVersions

$function:tabexpansion2 = $function:tabexpansion2 -replace 'End\r\n{','End { if ($null -ne $options) { $options += $global:options} else {$options = $global:options}'
```

The completer param names are important. Renaming them will make it not work.

Comment: Another critical piece was having that script run when the module is loaded. This was done by adding this to the .psd1: `ScriptsToProcess = 'ArgumentTabCompletion.ps1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [TabExpansion++ module](https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus), which was designed to make extending tab completion easier.

I just played with it for few minutes, and I think you want something like this based on the example:

```
Import-Module TabExpansion++

function PaketAddNugetCompletion
{
    [ArgumentCompleter(Parameter = 'Nuget', Command = 'Paket-Add')]
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameter)

    Paket-FindPackages -SearchText $wordToComplete |
        ForEach-Object {
            # not quite sure what property to use off the result, but this might work.
            New-CompletionResult -CompletionText $_ 
        }   
}
```

Comment: I posted my solution above. I'm marking this as the answer since it lead me to that solution.

Answer (score 1):

These are called [Dynamic parameters and are described in about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx).

> The following example shows a sample function with standard 
>   parameters named Name and Path, and an optional dynamic parameter
>   named DP1.The DP1 parameter is in the PSet1 parameter set and has a
>   type of Int32. The DP1 parameter is available in the Sample function
>   only when the value of the Path parameter contains "HKLM:", indicating
>   that it is being used in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry drive.

```psh
function Get-Sample {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ([String]$Name, [String]$Path)

    DynamicParam
    {
        if ($path -match ".*HKLM.*:")
        {
            $attributes = new-object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
            $attributes.Mandatory = $false
            $attributeCollection = new-object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

            $dynParam1 = new-object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("dp1", [Int32], $attributeCollection)

            $paramDictionary = new-object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $paramDictionary.Add("dp1", $dynParam1)
            return $paramDictionary
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's another example that does validation sets dynamically](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/06/10/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter.aspx).

---

I've re-read your question, and it looks like maybe you just want a static, pre-defined list of tab-completed values for a specific parameter. If that's the case, then you can simply [use the `[ValidateSet()]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714434(v=vs.85).aspx):

```psh
function Get-Something {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [ValidateSet('One','Two','Three')]
    [String]
    $MyParam
)
}
```

But if the values need to be determined at runtime, then see the above section on dynamic parameters instead.