# How do I prompt for a path to a directory with support for tab completion in the console?

Tags: powershell

I want to prompt the user for a directory path.

The user can enter some text like `C:\Pro` in command line, tap `tab` button and the script should autocomplete the text to`C:\Programs\` on another `tab` it should change the text to `C:\Program Files\`.

So, the script should scan folders and help user to navigate between them on typing.

**Important**: I can't use any GUI dialogs, because I am going to use the script on Win with no GUI.

This code will *not* work:

```
New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Complete User Input PowerShell 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114701/auto-complete-user-input-powershell-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... you don't have to? PS already does that by default?

```
function T
{ 
    param
    (
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $P
    )
    $P.FullName
}

T -P # Pressing <tab> at this stage will automatically show you the first file in your working directory. That happens even if the P was of type string.
```

Comment: Nothing would work in the context of `Read-Host` in the way that you want. `Read-Host` only processes the entries once you hit enter. There's no way around that as far as `Read-Host` is concerned. Then what you want to do is really look at `$Host.UI.RawUI` and look at using `ReadKey()`, that way you can filter on what the key pressed was and perform whatever code you want on that particular key press.

Comment: (I'm not the OP). I _inferred_ from the OP's question that `Read-Host` must be used, so - assuming that's the case - your answer doesn't help. You may want to add your clarification _directly to your answer_.

Comment: This doesn't work in a prompt for a mandatory script parameter.